# 'function' object is not iterable in list - python

Tags: python

I am making a game similar to the 'Google Dino game'. The issue is in the line

```
for cactus in list_of_cacti:
        move_cactus(cactus['rect'])
```

and

```
for cactus in list_of_cacti:
        display_surf.blit(cactus['surf'], cactus['rect'])
```

with the error stating "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable." How would I solve this issue? I have only included parts I think are necessary.

```py
import pygame, sys, random

def one_cactus(ground_surf_rect):
    cactus_width = 60
    cactus_height = 72
    cactus_dimensions = (cactus_width, cactus_height)
    cactus_surface = pygame.Surface(cactus_dimensions)
    cactus_surface_rect = cactus_surface.get_rect()
    cactus_surface_rect.bottomright = ground_surf_rect.topright
    cactus_surface.fill ('green')
    return cactus_surface, cactus_surface_rect

def move_cactus(cactus_surface_rect):
    movement_increment = -5            # moving left
    cactus_surface_rect.left += movement_increment
    return cactus_surface_rect

def cacti(number, ground_surf_rect):
    list_of_cacti = []
    start_x_coord = ground_surf_rect.width / 2    # start at the middle of the screen
    for i in range(number):
        current_cactus = {} # prepare empty dictionary to package surf and rect
        x_coord = start_x_coord + random.randint(200, 400)  # make the next cactus between 200 and 400
        cactus_surf, cactus_surf_rect = one_cactus(ground_surf_rect)
        cactus_surf_rect.left = x_coord     #a djust the x coordinate to the random one
        # now package the surface the the rect coordinates into one dictionary
        current_cactus['surf'] = cactus_surf
        current_cactus['rect'] = cactus_surf_rect
        # add the dictionary containing info about one cactus into a list
        list_of_cacti.append(current_cactus)
        start_x_coord = x_coord     # reset the startt x coordinate to that of the latest cactus
    return cacti

# main program
# the surf and rect variables are global, can be modified by all functions
display_surf, display_surf_rect = create_window()
background_colour = 'white'

ground_surf, ground_surf_rect = create_ground(display_surf_rect)
dino_surf, dino_surf_rect = create_dino(ground_surf_rect)
cactus_surf, cactus_surf_rect = one_cactus(ground_surf_rect)

list_of_cacti = cacti(5, ground_surf_rect)

jumping_variables = {
    'amount': 0,
    'gravity': 2
}

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    display_surf.fill(background_colour)

# handle key presses first to make things more responsive
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed_keys:
        move_dino(ground_surf_rect, pressed_keys)
        dino_jump(ground_surf_rect, pressed_keys)
    
    for cactus in list_of_cacti:
        move_cactus(cactus['rect'])

    display_surf.blit(ground_surf,ground_surf_rect)
    display_surf.blit(dino_surf, dino_surf_rect)
    display_surf.blit(cactus_surf,cactus_surf_rect)

    for cactus in list_of_cacti:
        display_surf.blit(cactus['surf'], cactus['rect'])
        
    update_window()
```

Comment: Typo: `cacti` returns itself, not the `list_of_cacti` you apparently meant to `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cacti function is returning itself, a function, which is not iterable. You want the function to return list_of_cacti. The updated function should look like this:

```
def cacti(number, ground_surf_rect):
list_of_cacti = []
start_x_coord = ground_surf_rect.width / 2    # start at the middle of the screen
for i in range(number):
    current_cactus = {} # prepare empty dictionary to package surf and rect
    x_coord = start_x_coord + random.randint(200, 400)  # make the next cactus between 200 and 400
    cactus_surf, cactus_surf_rect = one_cactus(ground_surf_rect)
    cactus_surf_rect.left = x_coord     #a djust the x coordinate to the random one
    # now package the surface the the rect coordinates into one dictionary
    current_cactus['surf'] = cactus_surf
    current_cactus['rect'] = cactus_surf_rect
    # add the dictionary containing info about one cactus into a list
    list_of_cacti.append(current_cactus)
    start_x_coord = x_coord     # reset the startt x coordinate to that of the latest cactus
return list_of_cacti
```